# Direct link to a CSV-formatted report

Tags: civireport, urls

I'm using CiviCRM as a WordPress plugin. I've created a report with a URL like:

https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/report/instance/123

I can visit that page and click the "Export CSV" button. Now, I want to write a script with the Google Sheets API that loads this CSV and updates a Google Sheet. Therefore, I need a direct link to the CSV-formatted report, so my script can issue an HTTP GET and receive the CSV data.

Is there a URL parameter I can pass, or some other way to directly link to the CSV?

Comment: Not really an answer but this might be tricky because the export csv button actually runs functions to compile the file and force the download using php header() and content-disposition attachment. See line 224 etc here to look at how it is working: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Report/Utils/Report.php. You could probably write an extension that invokes the functions to generate the csv based on what's going on here. Or perhaps one exists?

Comment: Thanks, that seems like an authoritative "No". If you submit your comment as an answer instead I'll accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be tricky because the export csv button actually runs functions to compile the file and force the download using php header() and content-disposition attachment. See line 224 etc here to look at how it is working: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Report/Utils/Report.php.

You could probably write an extension that invokes the functions to generate the csv based on what's going on here. Or perhaps one exists?